# QueryDsl date arithmetic issue (PostgreSQL behind) - function add_minutes(...) does not exist

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpql, querydsl

I am having an issue with QueryDsl date arithmetic. It does not work for me, throws a following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function add_minutes(timestamp with time zone, integer) does not exist
```

I am using PostgreSQL database, here is the version:

```
PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2, 64-bit
```

QueryDsl version is: `3.7.4`

This is the query code:

```
import static com.experthub.ws.model.QExpertAppointmentStatusChangeEntity.expertAppointmentStatusChangeEntity;
import static com.mysema.query.support.Expressions.dateTimeOperation;
import static com.mysema.query.types.expr.BooleanExpression.allOf;

public class ExpertAppointmentRepositoryImpl implements ExpertAppointmentRepositoryCustom {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public ExpertAppointmentRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public Integer getNumPendingAppointments(Integer userId, Date currentTime) {
        return (int) new JPAQuery(entityManager)
                .from(expertAppointmentStatusChangeEntity)
                .where(
                        allOf(
                                expertAppointmentStatusChangeEntity.expertAppointmentEntity().userExpertEntity().id.eq(userId),
                                dateTimeOperation(
                                        Date.class,
                                        Ops.DateTimeOps.ADD_MINUTES,
                                        expertAppointmentStatusChangeEntity.expertAppointmentEntity().appointmentTime,
                                        expertAppointmentStatusChangeEntity.expertAppointmentEntity().duration).after(currentTime)))
                .count();
    }
```

And this is what the entities looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "expert_appointment_status_change")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ExpertAppointmentStatusChangeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_expert_appointment", nullable = false)
    private ExpertAppointmentEntity expertAppointmentEntity;

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private Integer status;

    @Column(name = "change_time", nullable = false)
    private Date changeTime;

    @Column(name = "change_initiator", nullable = false)
    private Integer changeInitiator;

    @Column(name = "message", length = 512)
    private String message;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "expert_appointment")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ExpertAppointmentEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity userEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user_expert", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity userExpertEntity;

    @Column(name = "appointment_time", nullable = false)
    private Date appointmentTime;

    @Column(name = "duration", nullable = false)
    private Integer duration;

    // some other fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "expertAppointmentEntity")
    @OrderBy("changeTime DESC")
    private List<ExpertAppointmentStatusChangeEntity> expertAppointmentStatusChangeEntities;
}
```

I can't yet find any other way of doing this arithmetic.

I am aware of the existance of [this class](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/blob/master/querydsl-sql/src/main/java/com/querydsl/sql/PostgreSQLTemplates.java), but am not sure how to integrate it into my code.

Also trying to do this:

```
public class PostgreSQLJPQLTemplates extends JPQLTemplates {

    public PostgreSQLJPQLTemplates() {
        super();

        add(Ops.DateTimeOps.ADD_YEARS, "{0} + interval '{1s} years'");
        add(Ops.DateTimeOps.ADD_MONTHS, "{0} + interval '{1s} months'");
        add(Ops.DateTimeOps.ADD_WEEKS, "{0} + interval '{1s} weeks'");
        add(Ops.DateTimeOps.ADD_DAYS, "{0} + interval '{1s} days'");
        add(Ops.DateTimeOps.ADD_HOURS, "{0} + interval '{1s} hours'");
        add(Ops.DateTimeOps.ADD_MINUTES, "{0} + interval '{1s} minutes'");
        add(Ops.DateTimeOps.ADD_SECONDS, "{0} + interval '{1s} seconds'");
    }
}
```

And adding that as a second parameter to JPAQuery constructor:

```
// somwhere in code
PostgreSQLJPQLTemplates template = new PostgreSQLJPQLTemplates();

new JPAQuery(entityManager, template)
```

only caused a different issue.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to register the function in the dialect.

```
public class BimDB2Dialect extends DB2Dialect {

public BimDB2Dialect() {
    registerFunction("add_years", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "?1 + ?2 years"));
    registerFunction("add_months", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "?1 + ?2 months"));
    registerFunction("add_weeks", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "?1 + 7 * ?2 days"));
    registerFunction("add_days", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "?1 + ?2 days"));

}
```

}

See a thread [Date arithemtic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/querydsl/Dk5r3rlI4uI)

Comment: For the ones using MariaDB: I had to register the function like this:
`registerFunction("add_years", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "DATE_ADD(?1, INTERVAL ?2 YEAR)"));`

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me for postgres.

```
public class CustomPostgreSQL9Dialect extends PostgreSQL95Dialect{

    public CustomPostgreSQL9Dialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("add_years", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "?1 + interval '1 years' * ?2"));
        registerFunction("add_months", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "?1 + interval '1 months' * ?2"));
        registerFunction("add_weeks", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "?1 + interval '1 days' * 7 * ?2"));
        registerFunction("add_days", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "?1 + interval '1 days' * ?2"));
        registerFunction("add_minutes", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "?1 + interval '1 minutes' * ?2"));
    }
}
```

Set hibernate dialect

```
hibernate.dialect=<package>.CustomPostgreSQL9Dialect
```

Comment: How did you use add_days in hql?